# How can I find this bound?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ be compact and let $f:X\to\mathbb R^n$ be continuous. Given $\epsilon>0$, show that there is an $M$ such that for all $x, y\in X$,
$$\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq M\|x-y\|+\epsilon.$$

Why can't I find a uniform bound?

Comment: Because not all continuous functions are [Lipschitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)-continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ is compact and $f$ is continuous you have by the [Heine-Cantor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem) that $f$ is uniformly continuous. Thus, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\|x-y\|<\delta$ implies that $\|f(x)-f(y)\|<\varepsilon$. Now, consider the set $S=\{(x,y)\in X^2:\|x-y\|\geqslant \delta\}$. Since $S$ is a closed subset of the compact set $X^2$ we have that $S$ is compact. Now, the function $F:S\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\displaystyle (x,y)\mapsto \frac{\|f(x)-f(y)\|}{\|x-y\|}$ is continuous and thus has a maximum $M$. Now, let $x,y\in X$ be arbitrary. If $\|x-y\|<\delta$ then

$$\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leqslant \varepsilon\leqslant M\|x-y\|+\varepsilon$$

and if $\|x-y\|\geqslant \delta$ then $(x,y)\in S$ so that

$$\frac{\|f(x)-f(y)\|}{\|x-y\|}\leqslant M$$

and so

$$\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leqslant M\|x-y\|\leqslant M\|x-y\|+\varepsilon$$

Either way we have the desired bound for all $x,y\in X$.